# JPA force insert related entities (as opposed to update)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My Desired Behavior:

```
Make 
ID   |   City   |   Vers
1        Jose        S_5

MakeConfiguration
MakeID | Something | Vers
1         nada       S_5
```

When I get this entity (using spring data jpa with some custom @Query) then everything works fine.

When I try to post (the exact same entity), I want the following:

```
Make 
ID   |   City   |   Vers
1        Jose        S_5
1        Jose        S_6

MakeConfiguration
MakeID | Something | Vers
1         nada       S_5
1         nada       S_6
```

But what I get instead is this:

```
Make 
ID   |   City   |   Vers
1        Jose        S_5
1        Jose        S_6

MakeConfiguration
MakeID | Something | Vers
1         nada       S_6
```

(Notice the lack of new record created in MakeConfiguration)
The SQL that is being shown is inserting a new record into Make, and updating the record in MakeConfiguration with the new Version. If I alter any of the other @Id annotated values (something, in this case) then it correctly inserts a new record. It seems that hibernate is not respecting the @Id annotation on the version.

I have the following (JPA/Hibernate entities)

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MakeId.class)
public class Make {
    @Id
    @Column(name="MAKE_ID")
    private String makeUuid;

    @Id
    private String city

    @Id @Column(name = "MAKE_ID_VERSION")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "version_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "version_seq", strategy = "com.me.VersionIdGenerator"
    )
    private String makeIdVersion;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns( {
            @JoinColumn(name = "clientProgramUuid", referencedColumnName = "MAKE_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "clientUuidVersion", referencedColumnName = "MAKE_ID_VERSION")
    })
    private List<MakeConfiguration> makeConfigurations;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(MakeConfigurationId.class)
public class MakeConfiguration {
    @Id
    private String makeConfigurationUuid

    @Id
    private String something

    @Id
    private String makeIdVersion;
}
```

IdClass, getters, setters omitted for readability. VersionIdGenerator generates the next version in sequence (let us say S_1, S_2...S_N).

I also am always calling entitymanager.persist on Make entity.

I have tried several things to get this to work (bidirectional, etc.) and with no luck. I think that I need to force the version to be retrieved from what is generated by the Make.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your transactions... do you fetch the `MakeConfiguration` of version `5_5` and modify it? If so: does this all happen in one transaction? If yes: the entity is still attached and thus gets updated. This might be preventable if yout annotate the method fetching the `MakeConfiguration` with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: No, My only interaction is through rest API (get + post), so nothing should be attached still

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here... in your app, you need to have some code (probably a `Repository`) interacting with the database. There must be some transactions be involved. No transactions = no database interaction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use Eager) Use `FetchType.LAZY`.
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847289/ignore-a-fetchtype-eager-in-a-relationship)

Second, never use `@id` a lot. Use it only once per Entity. `@Id`: This annotation specifies the primary key of the entity. Even if you placing in the column id of some object - just simply use `@Column`
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603638/what-is-the-use-of-annotations-id-and-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype)

Btw, [download ProjectLombok](https://projectlombok.org/) library (for Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I fixed your program. It should look like this:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table
@Entity
public class Make {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "version_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "version_generator", sequenceName = "seq_version", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String makeUuid;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST
            }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<MakeConfiguration> makeConfigurations = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMakeConfigurations(MakeConfiguration makeConfiguration) {
        makeConfigurations.add(makeConfiguration);
    }

    public void removeMakeConfigurations(MakeConfiguration makeConfiguration) {
        makeConfigurations.remove(makeConfiguration);
    }

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table
@Entity
public class MakeConfiguration {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "makeConfig_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "makeConfig_generator", sequenceName = "seq_makeConfig", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String makeConfigurationUuid;

    @Column
    private String something;

    @Column
    private String version;
}
```